# Bumblebee + Intel HD graphics + GeForce GT 555M + Unity / compiz problem

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a `mx14r1 alienware` and I am using Ubuntu 13.04 raring with unity 7.0. I try to install `bumblebee` to use optimus technology with my `nvidia` card but didnt work.

I am trying to run `compiz-fusion` or/and `unity 3d` but both crash when i try to view. What is the right way to install all the drivers/bumblebee and how can I setup the `xorg.conf` to run `nvidia` card instead the `intel` hd graphics?

I am not worry with power saving and other kind of stuff. (I need to clean up my older instalation files of bumblebee?)

Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to unninstall your current bumblebee setup:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

If you want to keep some programs from the bumblebee repository, you can also suffice by removing Bumblebee only (including its dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Now to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

Optional packages you can install:
Just type sudo apt-get install "package'

bumblebee-nvidia: proprietary nvidia driver support (if installed, become default over nouveau)
virtualgl: VirtualGL as backend
virtualgl-libs-ia32: 32bit support for VirtualGL on 64bit system, necessary to run 32bit app through optirun
primus: primus/primusrun as backend (virtualgl Stays default, you need to run optirun -b primus )
primus-libs-ia32: 32bit support for primus/primurun on 64bit system, necessary to run 32bit app through optirun

Btw: I am on an M11xr2 :)

Comment: Tks, I will try these ^^

Comment: @ÂndersonIgnáciodaSilva did it work? I'm a bit afraid of installing linux-headers-generic, 'cause Ubuntu 12.04 actualy depends on another but similar package.